# How to remove the port number from a url string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code snippet:

```
string tmp = String.Format("<SCRIPT FOR='window' EVENT='onload' LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>javascript:window.open('{0}');</SCRIPT>", url);

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "NewWindow", tmp);
```

The URL generated by this code include the port number and I think that is happening because port 80 is used by the website and in this code I am trying to load a page from a virtual directory of the website. Any ideas on how to suppress the port number in the URL string generated by this code?

Comment: you should accept the best answer of your question by clicking on the thick under answer's score!

Answer (score 155):

Use the [`Uri.GetComponents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getcomponents.aspx) method. To remove the port component you'll have to combine all the other components, something like:

```
var uri = new Uri( "http://www.example.com:80/dir/?query=test" );
var clean = uri.GetComponents( UriComponents.Scheme | 
                               UriComponents.Host | 
                               UriComponents.PathAndQuery, 
                               UriFormat.UriEscaped );
```

EDIT: I've found a better way:

```
var clean = uri.GetComponents( UriComponents.AbsoluteUri & ~UriComponents.Port,
                               UriFormat.UriEscaped );
```

`UriComponents.AbsoluteUri` preservers all the components, so `& ~UriComponents.Port` will only exclude the port.

Comment: According to the latest edit: badly that i cannot upvote again. Super-elegant answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Usually you just "or" flags-enums, so I've almost forgotten you can use other bitwise operations.

Comment: very clean solution, just added a ToCleanUrl() extension to Uri

Comment: Danko solution was noy working for me with uri = new Uri("localhost:52798") so I used var clean = uri.OriginalString.Replace(":" + uri.LocalPath,""); which looks ugly but works

Comment: To clear port you can use `.setPort(-1)` and to clean *string* components you can use `.setUserInfo(null)` the null will do the trick

Answer (score 97):

```
UriBuilder u1 = new UriBuilder( "http://www.example.com:80/dir/?query=test" );
u1.Port = -1;
string clean = u1.Uri.ToString();
```

Setting the `Port` property to `-1` on `UriBuilder` will remove any explicit port and implicitly use the default port value for the protocol scheme.

Comment: I found just skipping `u1.Port = -1;` in this solution worked for me - though the one above will also exclude any port number, not just 80, so that may still be useful for some cases.

Comment: Note that you may want to use `.AbsoluteUri`, not `.ToString` https://stackoverflow.com/a/7624992/29

Comment: Calling `Uri` is not needed after setting the `Port` to _-1_. Instead, it can simply be `string clean = u1.ToString();`

Answer (score 51):

A more generic solution (works with http, https, ftp...) based on [Ian Flynn idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21887134/1195872).
This method does not remove custom port, if any.
Custom port is defined automatically depending on the protocol.

```cs
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://www.google.fr/");
    if (uriBuilder.Uri.IsDefaultPort)
    {
        uriBuilder.Port = -1;
    }
    return uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
```

**April 2021 update**

With newer .NET versions, `Uri.AbsoluteUri` removes the default ports and retains the custom port by default. The above code-snippet is equivalent to:

```cs
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://www.google.fr/");
    return uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
```

Comment: Perfectionist ;) +1

Comment: Note that you may want to use `.AbsoluteUri`, not `.ToString` https://stackoverflow.com/a/7624992/29

Comment: Doesn't `.AbsoluteUri` strip off default ports by default? Do we even need the first part?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma it seems to have changed with latest .net frameworks.

Answer (score 8):

I would use the [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) for this. I have not tried, but it seems it's [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring.aspx) will actually output what you want:

```
var url = new Uri("http://google.com:80/asd?qwe=asdff");
var cleanUrl = url.ToString();
```

If not, you can combine the components of the `url`-members to create your `cleanUrl` string.

Comment: That does not remove ports other than the default. (80, in most cases)

Comment: yup, missed "The string returned by this method does not contain port information when the port is the default port for the scheme." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring.aspx) when wrote my answer

Comment: @Jens: it should not remove another ports. Only 80 is supposed to be default for http scheme. If you remove any port - then you will get url that points to another resource.

Answer (score 4):

```
var url = "http://google.com:80/asd?qwe=zxc#asd";
var regex = new Regex(@":\d+");
var cleanUrl = regex.Replace(url, "");
```

the solution with `System.Uri` is also possible but will be more bloated.

Comment: Wont that replace all :xxx occurrences say if thers one in the querystring

Comment: That regex will ruin an URI like `http://asdf.com:80/asdf?something:12:34:56`. (Granted, that URI should be properly encoded but you cannot be sure it is)

Comment: @Isak: You could use `@"(?<![^/]/[^/]*):\d+"` to avoid that.

Comment: @Isak: i'm not sure that we should operate with misconstructed urls. RFC mandates that ":" in query path should be encoded as %3A. dot.

Comment: yeah I know but I prefer to write bulletproof code and not assume anything about the input

Comment: One line it :)
url = Regex.Replace(url, @":\d+", "");

Comment: I would not recommend using string manipulation when other more thoroughly tested solutions (such as Uri, UriBuilder, etc.) are available.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the UriBuilder and set the value of the port to -1

and the code will be like this:

```
Uri tmpUri = new Uri("http://LocalHost:443/Account/Index");
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(tmpUri);
builder.Port = -1;
Uri newUri = builder.Uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [the properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder_properties(VS.80).aspx) of [URIBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(VS.80).aspx) for this, it has properties for outputting an url the way you want

Comment: Guys, I am trying to suppress the port number before the command generate the url string.  I am also open to an equivalent solution if is is not possible to use this command.

Comment: please note the contents of the tmp variable is:
<SCRIPT FOR='window' EVENT='onload' LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>javascript:window.open('../Gradebook/AcademicHonestyGrid.aspx?StudentID=35832&ClassSectionId=8487&uid=yjoEG2CuaptYAyqOEPwBFSbAarVk%...(omited due to encrypted and too long)

Comment: looks to me like something in the .net framework or IIS is adding the http://localhost:port number

Comment: Use the `UriBuilder.Uri` property, then you can use the template shown in the top answer in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks I figured it out...used the KISS principle...

```
string redirectstr = String.Format(
   "http://localhost/Gradebook/AcademicHonestyGrid.aspx?StudentID={0}&ClassSectionId={1}&uid={2}", 
   studid, 
   intSectionID, 
   HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encrypter.Encrypt(uinfo.ToXml())));

Response.Redirect(redirectstr );
```

works fine for what I am doing which is a test harness