# How to remove PROTOCOL from URI

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can I remove the protocol from URI? i.e. remove HTTP

Comment: (minor point, but that is the *scheme* in uri terminology)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use this the `System.Uri` class like this:

```
System.Uri uri = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=something");
string uriWithoutScheme = uri.Host + uri.PathAndQuery + uri.Fragment;
```

This will give you *stackoverflow.com/search?q=something*

**Edit:** this also works for *about:blank* :-)

Comment: This works fine if you assume port 80, otherwise there's a Port property on the Uri class which should be checked then appended with the preceding colon.

Comment: There's `Uri.Authority` which is `Uri.Host` + `Uri.Port`.

Comment: Note this can add a trailing slash so you might want to do a .TrimEnd('/'), e.g. http://foo.com becomes foo.com/

Comment: To strip **www** check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969214/how-to-strip-http-and-www-from-an-entered-domain-name-using-c-sharp)

Comment: This solution does not consider `Uri.Fragment`.

Comment: Rather than concatenating stuff, you could use the uri.GetLeftPart and substring out the scheme. e.g. `string uriWithoutScheme = uri.ToString().Substring(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Scheme).Length);` or something?

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get that to work how you wrote it. I got it working by writing it like this as it cannot find 'System.Uri'. I tried adding in a dependency but found no Uri of sorts. 
            `var uri = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com");
            var result = uri.Host + uri.PathAndQuery + uri.Fragment;`

Comment: To preserve port number ([inspired by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819529/666166)):
`uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri & ~UriComponents.Scheme, UriFormat.UriEscaped);`

Comment: GetComponents version doesn't preserve the port for me, also both answers break if schema is already not provided and seem to escape... '?' in query string...

Answer (score 19):

The best (and to me most beautiful) way is to use the [`Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class for parsing the string to an absolute URI and then use the [`GetComponents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getcomponents(v=vs.110).aspx) method with the correct [`UriComponents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7767559y(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration to remove the scheme:

```
Uri uri;
if (Uri.TryCreate("http://stackoverflow.com/...", UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
{
    return uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri &~ UriComponents.Scheme, UriFormat.UriEscaped);
}
```

For further reference: the `UriComponents` enumeration is a decorated with the [`FlagsAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), so bitwise operations (eg. `&` and `|`) can be used on it. In this case the `&~` removes the bits for `UriComponents.Scheme` from `UriComponents.AbsoluteUri` using the AND operator in combination with the bitwise complement operator.

Answer (score 15):

In the *general* sense (not limiting to http/https), an (absolute) uri is always a *scheme* followed by a colon, followed by scheme-specific data. So the only safe thing to do is cut at the scheme:

```
    string s = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517240/";
    int i = s.IndexOf(':');
    if (i > 0) s = s.Substring(i + 1);
```

In the case of http and a few others you may also want to `.TrimStart('/')`, but this is **not** part of the scheme, and is not guaranteed to exist. Trivial example: `about:blank`.

Comment: Very well that you included the explanation for not always trimming for '/'.

Comment: If port is a part of the url, we might be in trouble. "stackoverflow.com:80/" as an example

Comment: @Skuli good point, however String.IndexOf() returns the first occurrence of the colon string, so I think a port in the URL would not matter (it'd be the second occurrence of the colon) and this is still the safest and best answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the most beautiful way, but try something like this:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com");
var scheme = uri.Scheme;
var result = uri.ToString().SubString(scheme.Length + 3);
```

Comment: I just got a notification about this answer being edited. Wow, did I really write that in 2010? This is an awful answer :). The accepted one is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the RegEx for this. The below sample would meet your need.

```
    using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string txt="http://www.google.com";

      string re1="((?:http|https)(?::\\/{2}[\\w]+)(?:[\\/|\\.]?)(?:[^\\s\"]*))";    // HTTP URL 1

      Regex r = new Regex(re1,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
      Match m = r.Match(txt);
      if (m.Success)
      {
            String httpurl1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
            Console.Write("("+httpurl1.ToString()+")"+"\n");
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: What on earth earned this post a -1? +1 unless I hear a good argument otherwise. Downvoting without explanation helps no one. This solution appears valid, even if some might think it is a poor approach.

Comment: it looks just for 2 from potentially unlimited number of schemes.

Comment: Mike, if that's the case you should probably accompany an explanation with the downvote with the intention to remove it if the answer is fixed. Could be an honest mistake for all you know; putting the -1 back on.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers work in most cases, but IMO it's not a complete solution:

```
uri.Host + uri.PathAndQuery + uri.Fragment;
```

drops port if specified (e.g. http://www.example.com:8080/path/ becomes [www.example.com/path/](http://www.example.com/path/) )

```
uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri & ~UriComponents.Scheme, UriFormat.UriEscaped)
```

preserves ports and seems generally better, but in some cases, (which are most likely to be incorrect, but not impossible), I got some characters escaped that shouldn't.

- In both cases we get '/' added at the end, so if your url is potentially sensitive to that difference, or you care how it looks, you need need to check if it was present before and if not TrimEnd it.
- On top of that both of those solution throw exception if Uri is considered invalid, so if your url already doesn't have the 'schema' (e.g. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) the code above fails.

If you want something really generic and working for input over which you might not have control (e.g. user input), I'd probably stick to a simpler solution, e.g:

```
var endOfSchemaIdx = url.IndexOf("://");
if(endOfSchemaIdx != -1)
    return url.Substring(endOfSchemaIdx+3);
return url;
```

You can also fetch the schema via a library like FLURL (doesn't throw exception on [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) and look up the first occurrence of "url.Schema" + "://", then delete it if exists. I feel safer if the rest of the url is not processed by any library, unless that is your intention.