# How to strip http:// and www. from an entered domain name using c#

Tags: c#, regex

In the application I am working on, we allow user to enter a list of domain names, we expect the user to enter the domain names in any on the following formats

- [stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com)
- [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com)
- [http://stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com)
- http://www.stackoverflow.com

but when storing this domain names back into our databases, we want to store the domain name in the following format only

**Format : stackoverflow.com**

So wanted to know if there is a ready made helper that I can use to get this job done, or any suggestions to do this in an efficient manner.

**[What have I tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)**

This is what I came up with,

```
public static string CleanDomainName(string domain)
{
    domain = domain.Trim();
    if (domain.Split('.').Count() > 2)
    {
        domain = domain.Split('.')[1] + "." + domain.Split('.')[2];
    }
    return domain;
}
```

Please help me out on this.

Comment: You can parse the uri with the `Uri` class and pick apart its components through various properties. However, have you considered subdomains that are *not* "www" in your intended solution?

Comment: Also, there's *no guarantee* that "www.example.com" will map to "example.com", unless you're specifically aware that the domain does this.

Comment: `www.x.com` is a different host to `x.com` and is best treated as such.

Comment: I think you must use regular expression.

Comment: 5 answers, 5 comments :) but whats with the 2 down votes ? crazy !

Comment: Looks like two peeps have gone crazy with the downvotes across the board on this question. Bad luck!

Comment: Yeah, I don't really get that. It's a valid question that only needs a little bit more clarification - for example, why www. needs to be stripped when it will result in a *different* domain name. =)

Comment: In my opinion the _problem_ of these parsing/regex approach is that it always assumes the URI will/may start with "www." but it's not true. A more robust approach should check (well **if it's really needed**) the **server response** removing part by part peaces from the URI (to determine when the response is different or when you reach another server). For example you  may compare the server HTTP response or simply check which IP will reply to your **PING requests**.

Answer (score 6):

use Regex to replace the expressions in the beginning of the string:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"^(?:http(?:s)?://)?(?:www(?:[0-9]+)?\.)?", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

this will replace:

- an eventual "http://" in the beginning (or "https://") followed by
- an eventual "www."  (also with a number following ie: www8 or www23)

Comment: it does. it matches "www." --> gets removed. Are you sure you use the return value of the method?

Comment: @tried this http://pastebin.com/XGMs08Xd, god ! votes are flying all around this post. Upvoting your answer.

Comment: @fix_likes_coding why you no use RegexOptions.IgnoreCase?

Comment: @fix_likes_coding you can use regex.ignorecase if the url is in caps or mixed format, and it does removes www. but does not other formats like www2,www3 and www7.

Comment: I think it's a **good answer**, just update to make it case insensitive and to "accept" and optional number (with any number of digits) after "www". It can't address all _strange_ URIs but it's pretty **simple and straightforward** and probably it's the best you can do with a **passive approach**.

Comment: edited it inside (the wwwxx and ignoreCase). But honestly i think it should not remove a wwwxx --> it could really be intended.

Comment: @yasser: the version you tried is an old one --> http:// was not yet optional, now it is

Comment: @fix_likes_coding yes it's intended but if he/she wants to map www.something.com to something.com then he/she has to map www2.something.com to something.com as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class.

```
string url = "http://www.testsite.com/path/file.html";
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
```

There are various [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri_properties%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) do retrieve different parts of the url.

Use uri.Host to get the `www.testsite.com` portion of the url. A little string manipulation can remove the `www.`;

```
string domain = uri.Host;
if (domain.StartsWith("www."))
{
    domain = domain.Substring(4);
}
```

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't answer the question. Parsing `stackoverflow.com` (example 1 above) as a Uri is an uncaught exception.

Comment: What with "www2." or, for example, http://something.www.domain.com? In my opinion the _problem_ of this parsing/regex approach is that it always assumes the URI will/may start with "www." but it's not always true. A more robust approach should check (well **if it's really needed**) the **server response** removing part by part peaces from the URI (to determine when the response is different or when you reach another server).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `System.Uri` class.

```
 System.Uri uri = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=something");
 string uriWithoutScheme = uri.Host.Replace("www.","") + uri.PathAndQuery;
```

This will give you: `stackoverflow.com/search?q=something`

Answer (score -1):

```
public static string CleanDomainName(string url)
{
    var uri = url.Contains("http://") ? new Uri(url) : new Uri("http://" + url);
    var parts = uri.Host.Split('.');
    return string.Join(".", parts.Skip(parts.Length - 2));
}
```

Comment: I tried this out myself, and worked perfectly. I would also like to know why people downvote this? I see the old one was not as perfect, but still if there is a flaw, a comment is always helpful.

Answer (score -2):

```
/// <summary>
/// Clears the sub domains from a URL.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="url">The URL.</param>
/// <returns>String for a URL without any subdomains</returns>
private static string ClearUrlSubDomains(Uri url)
{
    var host = url.Host.ToLowerInvariant();
    if (host.LastIndexOf('.') != host.IndexOf('.'))
    {
        host = host.Remove(0, host.IndexOf('.') + 1); // Strip out the subdomain (i.e. remove en-gb or www etc)
    }
    return host;
}
```

You can create a new Uri from your domain so calling it will be:

```
ClearUrlSubDomains(new Uri(domain))
```

This doesn't address urls like http://www.something.somethingelse.com but can be modified to do so with a while construct of equivalent.