# UriBuilder appending :443 to the URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, chatbot

I am trying to add a query string to the URL, therefore I am using UriBuilder. But for some reason it is converting "/" to :443 and I have no clue.

```html
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder($"https://chats.landbot.io/v3/{Id}/index.html");
            var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
            query["name"] = Name;
            query["planid"] = planId.ToString();
            uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
            var link = uriBuilder.ToString();
            return link;
```

The above code is returning "https://chats.landbot.io:443/v3/I8NCX/index.html?planid=46ff2d9fb8edf63b&name=Alex+SysAdmin"

I don't know why :443 is being added to the URL. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the port number from a url string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819336/how-to-remove-the-port-number-from-a-url-string)

Comment: This is automatic - port 443 is the default for HTTPS

Answer (score 3):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use the uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder($"https://chats.landbot.io/v3/aa/index.html");
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
        query["name"] = "aaa";
        query["planid"] = "bbb";
        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
        var link = uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
```

Result:

[image]